# Icinga2 repository service remove "disk C:"

Tags: monitoring, icinga

I am new to icinga2 and using repository.d and "node update-config" to get services of client.

I am using it for windows server.

I don't want multiple entries for disk monitoring like "disk" and "disk C:" to get added.

Is it possible to remove "disk C:" from repository?
I don't want this service to get added for further window server.

Answer (score 0):

On your remote windows machine, you have just to delete

```
  vars.disks["disk C:"] = {
    disk_partition = "C:"
  }
```

from your host.conf file, reload the daemon `icinga2.exe daemon -C` and restart icinga2 `Restart-Service icinga2`.
Don't forget to update your node config on your monitoring server `icinga2 node update-config`